# C++ Data Types vs. C# Data Types

Tags: c#, c++, types

As a professional C# programmer learning C++, I would like to keep data types the same as in C#. I wrote a header file that should help with this. What I want to know is if it is correct.

```
// boolean
//#DEFINE bool char
//#DEFINE true 0x01
//#DEFINE false 0x00

// 8-bit integers
#DEFINE byte unsigned char
#DEFINE UInt8 unsigned char
#DEFINE Byte unsigned char
#DEFINE sbyte char
#DEFINE Int8 char
#DEFINE SByte char

// 16-bit integers
#DEFINE ushort unsigned short int
#DEFINE UInt16 unsigned short int
#DEFINE short short int
#DEFINE Int16 short int

// 32-bit integers
#DEFINE uint unsigned int
#DEFINE UInt32 unsigned int
//#DEFINE int int
#DEFINE Int32 int

// 64-bit integers
#DEFINE long long long
#DEFINE Int64 long long
#DEFINE ulong unsigned long long
#DEFINE UInt64 unsigned long long

// 32-bit floating point
//#DEFINE float float
#DEFINE Single float

// 64-bit floating point
//#DEFINE double double
#DEFINE Double double
```

Comment: Use typedef, not define. I don't think double is guaranteed to be 64 bits either (I think GCC uses 96).

Comment: If there's a chance that another developer will ever work on this code, please consider investing the time to learn standard c++ types.

Comment: If you want fixed width types, have a look at [cstdint](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) (or the [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/integer/doc/html/boost_integer/cstdint.html) implementation for non-C++11 compilers/libraries).

Comment: I would suggest `cstdint` (C++11) or `stdint.h` (extension) for any type aliases. As others have pointed out trying to create C++# does not benefit you or any one else.

Comment: Uppercase preprocessor directives?  Oh the inhumanity!

Comment: Also, it's not correct.  What do you think `#define long long long` is going to do to existing code using `long long`?

Comment: @BenVoigt long long is 64-bits. Also, the code won't have any long longs

Comment: I used the official C++ website though http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables/

Comment: That's not the official C++ website. C++ doesn't even really have an official website, it has a standard. And no `long long` is only guaranteed to be at least 64-bits, it may be more.

Comment: The whole point of typedef is to create your own type as an alias of another, without all of the problems #define has.

Comment: After `#define ulong unsigned long long` causes replacement in certain contexts, those `long` tokens will be matched against `#define long long long`, creating `unsigned long long long long`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aside from the horrendous style, these macros don't even work the way you expect.

```
#define long long long
```

is prone to all sorts of problems.

http://ideone.com/Jg9DK

Reversing the order of the macro definitions doesn't fix the problem completely either.

http://ideone.com/45wUS

Similar problems occur with

```
#define short short int
```

http://ideone.com/dERGm

Answer (score 10):

Built-in types in C++ have an implementation defined size, while C# does not. If you want equivalent behavior then use the typedefs in `<cstdint>`. Not only the bytes, but the number of bits too! Also, `char` may or may not be `signed` - use `signed char` instead.

Although whatever you're doing sounds like a terrible idea. Just learn C++, not some silly hybrid language.