# Change all the int type to another type using #define for large program

Tags: c++, c

I want to change all my `int` type in my program to support arbitrary position integer. I chose to use `GMP`.

I am thinking about is it possible to do a `#define` to replace all `int` to `mpz_class`.

I start by a small program

```
#include <iostream>
#define int long long int
using namespace std;

int main(){
    // .... code
}
```

The compiler is already complaining about `main` have to return an `int` type.

Is it possible to add exception to `#define`? or this is a really bad idea to do so?

Comment: That sounds really dangerous.

Comment: Do not do this. Use a `typedef` and change the `ints` to use this instead. Otherwise all sorts of things (header files etc, linker problems) will fail.

Comment: This is undefined behaviour AFAIK. I believe the wording regarding this is "ill-formed". Eh, guess not, but *A translation unit shall not #define or #undef names lexically identical to keywords,* ***to the identiﬁers listed
in Table 3,*** *or to the attribute-tokens described in 7.6.*

Comment: You don't necessarily want to change *all* "int" to GMP "Big Integers".  And you should absolutely *not* "alias" int with a global #define.  Your best bet is manual search-and-replace (IMHO).  ADDED BENEFIT: you'll probably come up with ideas for refactoring your code to localize the use of your "Big Integers"...

Comment: what are u trying to do with this statement #define int long long int

Comment: @chris: Something cannot be both ill-formed and undefined.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, Yeah, that wasn't pro thinking on my part.

Comment: Redefining such a basic type will break any API using that type, including the API for `main` as you've discovered. Don't do it. Editors generally have global find/replace, and you can go back and fix the errors that you introduce.

Comment: so it is better to do it manually and chaning them one by one? I am afraid I will miss some of them if I do it in this way

Comment: @TimothyLeung: You're stuck doing that, because you didn't think ahead and design with `typedef`s!

Comment: So the proper way to do it is to `typedef` a `type` to a generic word? So next time I can simply change the typedef?

Comment: @TimothyLeung - Yes. Also is more descriptive of the return/parameter type

Comment: @TimothyLeung: Yeah, I mean, don't go over the top with it or anything, but this seems like it would have been a fairly decent candidate for such treatment.

Comment: Next you'll be all `#define private public` and it'll be dogs and cats living together, mass hysteria!

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ Data Types vs. C# Data Types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10476353/c-data-types-vs-c-sharp-data-types)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Redefining a keyword is *prohibited* iff you include any standard headers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9109427/560648).** Here, you included `<iostream>` so your program is ill-formed.

Otherwise, knock yourself out! Wait, no, don't, because this would still be really silly.

Instead, refactor your code to use some new type called, say, `my_integer` (but with a much better name):

```
typedef int my_integer;
```

Then, when you want to change from `int` to `mpz_class`, you just change the definition of `my_integer`:

```
typedef mpz_class my_integer;
```

Answer (score 1):

use main without int like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#define int long long int
using namespace std;

main(){
    // .... code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer: although technically possible you are **not** allowed to `#define` any of the reserved identifiers.